# How to convert a timestamp into a date and time?

Tags: python

How can I convert the following `20230820T2253` to `20/08/2023 22:53:00`

I have a file with the following format:

```
Apples 20230824T0005
Bananas 20230824T1825
Pears  20230824T2002
Orange  20230802T1949
Grapes 20230803T0046
```

Comment: Use `datetime.strptime()` in Python.

Comment: You can also do it with `awk` and a bunch of `substr()` calls to extract each part of the timestamp, followed by `printf()` to print it in the desired format.

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.